# 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment' error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am making a blog in django and am trying to implement this algorithm (algo.py) to the search question option in one of my pages.The algorithm takes input from the user and should display the sorted results list on the basis of scores of each question.

algo.py

```
import string
import math
from consult.models import Question, Reply


def main(search_text):
    search_words = split_text(search_text)
    idf_array = [0] * len(search_words)

    for i in range(0, len(search_words)):
        idf_array[i] = idf(search_words[i])

    score = [0] * Question.objects.all().count()
    k = -1
    for post in Question.objects.all():
        k += 1
        score[k] = scores(post, search_words, idf_array)

    sorted_list = Question.objects.all()
    quickSort(score, sorted_list)
    return sorted_list


def split_text(text):
    text_words = [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in text.split()]
    stop_words = {'with', 'at', 'from', 'into', 'of', 'on', 'by', 'and', 'after', 'how',
              'since', 'but', 'for', 'to', 'in', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'who', 'whom', 'why'}
for w1 in stop_words:
    for w2 in text_words:
        if w1 == w2:
            text_words.remove(w1)
return text_words


def idf(term):
    cnt = 0
    for post in Question.objects.all():
        title_words = split_text(post.title)
        body_words = split_text(post.body)
        answers_words = []
        ans = Reply.objects.filter(name=post)
        for a in ans:
            a_words = split_text(a.text)
            answers_words = answers_words + a_words

        words = title_words + answers_words + body_words
        for t in words:
            if t == term:
                cnt += 1
                break

    idf_value = math.log(Question.objects.all().count() / cnt)
    return idf_value


def scores(post, search_words, idf_array):
    df_array = [0] * len(search_words)
    title_words = split_text(post.title)
    body_words = split_text(post.body)
    answers_words = []
    ans = Reply.objects.filter(name=post)
    for a in ans:
        a_words = split_text(a.text)
        answers_words = answers_words + a_words
    words = title_words + answers_words + body_words

    j = -1
    for wrd1 in search_words:
        j += 1
        for wrd2 in words:
            if wrd1 == wrd2:
                df_array[j] += 1 / len(words)
    sum = 0
    for l in range(0, len(search_words)):
    sum += idf_array[l] * df_array[l]
    return sum


def quickSort(alist, a2):
    quickSortHelper(alist, a2, 0, len(alist) - 1)


def quickSortHelper(alist, a2, first, last):
    if first < last:
        splitpoint = partition(alist, a2, first, last)

        quickSortHelper(alist, a2, first, splitpoint - 1)
        quickSortHelper(alist, a2, splitpoint + 1, last)


def partition(alist, a2, first, last):
    pivotvalue = alist[first]
    leftmark = first + 1
    rightmark = last

    done = False
    while not done:

        while leftmark <= rightmark and alist[leftmark] >= pivotvalue:
            leftmark = leftmark + 1

        while alist[rightmark] <= pivotvalue and rightmark >= leftmark:
            rightmark = rightmark - 1

        if rightmark < leftmark:
            done = True
        else:
            temp = alist[leftmark]
            temp1 = a2[leftmark]
            alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
            a2[leftmark] = a2[rightmark]
            alist[rightmark] = temp
            a2[rightmark] = temp1

    temp = alist[first]
    temp1 = a2[first]
    alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
    a2[first] = a2[rightmark]
    alist[rightmark] = temp
    a2[rightmark] = temp1

    return rightmark
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
s = request.POST.get('search')
lis = algo.main(s)
return render(request, 'consult/search.html', {'comment': lis})
```

When i run my server and type the search query i get the error "'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment"

Please help me out considering the fact that I am new to both python and django

Comment: You need to show where the error happens, and the full message, we can't read your mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just because you are passing a queryset into the `quickSort` fucntion which is expecting a list. You can cast the queryset as a list and it should fix the issue

```
sorted_list = list(Question.objects.all())
```